# Is there a difference between horizon and comoving distances?

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, distance

I wonder if there a difference between horizon and comoving distances in cosmology ?

I mean both correspond to a null geodesic $(ds^2=0)$ right ?

Comment: They are completely different things. A *comoving distance* is just a distance measured in comoving coordinates i.e. a proper distance divided by the scale factor so it is does not change as the universe expands.

Comment: yes, but horizon distance is the distance in comoving coordinate, as horizon distance is $$d_{horizon}(t)=a(t)\int\limits_0^t\frac{cdt'}{a(t')} $$

with $a(t)$ beeing the scale factor.
Am I right ?

Comment: Is the difference just that for a comoving distance the integration bounderies changes ? Please help